# How to delete a character with leading and trailing whitespaces?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file containing characters with leading and trailing whitespaces and I would like to simply remove that character.

So far, the following works for leading whitespaces while the colon represents the character to be removed:

```
grep -v '^\s*;$' "input_file" > "output_file".tmp
mv "output_file".tmp "input_file"
```

Now I would like to remove the character when there are trailing spaces as well.

Assuming I have a file like this:

```
Some Text
; 
;
Some Text again
;
Some Text once again
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Some Text
Some Text again
Some Text once again
```

Comment: Since when does grep understand `\s`?

Comment: Well, it works so far.

Comment: I bet it doesn't.

Comment: I bet it does..

Comment: Btw, this is not a matter of discussion or smth like that. If you doubt it, try it.

Comment: Could you clarify what/when you want to remove, maybe by  providing an example from your file? And does your current command actually replace anything? Maybe give an example with a string rather than a file as input.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output for better clarity.

Comment: The answer to my question is: Since GNU grep 2.6, but it was only documented in 2.7. If you're not using GNU grep (or a version before 2.6), `\s` won't work.

Comment: Are you simply looking for `^\s*;\s*$`?

Comment: Oh yeah, `^\s*;\s*$` already did the job. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you actually want to use `sed`, `sed -iE '/^\s*;\s*$/d' input_file`

Comment: Hmm, but  `grep` works so far. What's the benefit of using `sed` instead? Is it faster?

Comment: in this case, grep would be faster.. sed is useful if you want to change portion of a line, search and replace, etc.. sed supports most of the filtering options of grep and  has some more of its own too.. `sed -i` is convenient for in-place editing, but internally it does temp+mv like you've used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `sed` in a trivial manner, e.g.

```
$ sed '/^\s*;\s*$/d' file
Some Text
Some Text again
Some Text once again
```

**Explanation**

Using the `sed` general delete form of `sed '/regex/d'` to deleting lines within the file matching *regex*. Above, *regex* is:

- `^` anchor the start of regex at beginning of line;
- `\s*` match zero-or-more whitespace;
- `;` match the *semi-colon*;
- `\s*$` match zero-or-more whitespace to the end of line;

Taken together, the regex will delete any line within the file containing only a *semi-colon* and whitespace.

To modify the file "in-place", add the `-i` option and to create a backup of the original file in `file.bak`, use the `-i.bak` form of the option.